# I want to rearrange an array according to row and column positions, how can I do it in Python?

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, matrix

In R I manage to do it, the idea is to do it in Python, if I apply `M[index]` in Python, the order is different from the result in R.

Code in R:

```
> M = matrix(c("a",0,"z",
+               0,0,"b",
+               "c","y",0), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "a"  "0"  "z" 
[2,] "0"  "0"  "b" 
[3,] "c"  "y"  "0" 
> 
> index = c(3,2,1)
> 
> M[index,index]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "0"  "y"  "c" 
[2,] "b"  "0"  "0" 
[3,] "z"  "0"  "a" 
>
```

Code in Python:

```
M = np.array([["a",0,"z"],
                  [0,0,"b"],
                  ["c","y",0]])
index = [2,1,0]

print(M[index])
array([['c', 'y', '0'],
       ['0', '0', 'b'],
       ['a', '0', 'z']], dtype='<U1')
```

Comment: try to use the OrderedDict as explained here https://pymotw.com/2/collections/ordereddict.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.flipud`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flipud.html) and [`np.fliplr`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fliplr.html#numpy.fliplr):

```
>>> M = np.array([["a",0,"z"],
                  [0,0,"b"],
                  ["c","y",0]])
>>> np.fliplr(np.flipud(M))
array([['0', 'y', 'c'],
       ['b', '0', '0'],
       ['z', '0', 'a']], dtype='<U1')
```

Or you can rotate by 90 degrees, twice, with [`np.rot90`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html#numpy.rot90):

```
>>> np.rot90(M, 2)
array([['0', 'y', 'c'],
       ['b', '0', '0'],
       ['z', '0', 'a']], dtype='<U1')
```

If you prefer to do it by indices, you can do:

```
>>> index = [2,1,0]
>>> M[index, ::-1]
array([['0', 'y', 'c'],
       ['b', '0', '0'],
       ['z', '0', 'a']], dtype='<U1')
# or,
>>> M[::-1, index]
array([['0', 'y', 'c'],
       ['b', '0', '0'],
       ['z', '0', 'a']], dtype='<U1')
```

Which is, essentially, similar to:

```
>>> M[::-1, ::-1]
array([['0', 'y', 'c'],
       ['b', '0', '0'],
       ['z', '0', 'a']], dtype='<U1')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. but what happens if i change the order of the index like this  `index = [2,0,1]` The method is no longer useful to me. `array([['c', 'y', '0'], ['a', '0', 'z'],   ['0', '0', 'b']], dtype='<U1')` the real result is: `[[ "0"  "c"  "y" ],[ "z"  "a"  "0" ],["b"  "0"  "0"]] `

Comment: `M[[2,0,1],:][:,[2,0,1]]`